# Adding a condition to the showcase

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, impala

The task is as follows. I have a code that has a huge number of attributes. And to one of the attributes, let's say this is the card type card_type='universal', you need to add the following condition:
case when card>='129897' and card<='293965'then 'unnamed' and card>='093750' and card <='903750' then 'personal' end as parameter
The attribute itself is as follows :select case when card_sybtype in ('VISA','MS') then 'universal'
At the same time, I do not need to output this to the final script, but I need this feature to be present in the script. That is, I need it to be linked only to the card type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a nested case when.
And if you dont want to select parameter column, you can use a subquery to hide the columns. So, in case you want it, just add it to the outside select list.

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM 
(SELECT 
col1, col2,
case when card_sybtype in ('VISA','MS')  THEN -- universal case
         case when card>='129897' and card <='293965' then 'unnamed' 
              when card>='093750' and card <='903750' then 'personal' end 
     else null
end as param_adhoc
FROM tab
) rs
```

Comment: gives a syntactic error in line 6.  I can't understand why

Comment: Could you pls check now?

Comment: I tried to do it. now the error is in line 9. underline operator AS

Comment: i think this may be choosing parameter as keyword. You can use updated SQL now.